# Cannot permanently disable httpd on Mac 10.14 Mojave after upgrade

Tags: macos, apache, macos-mojave

I'm running Mojave on a Mac Pro. Prior to this version of the OS I used Apple's Server app to manage Apache/httpd. Now I can't seem to permanently kill or stop httpd. Something keeps it alive and restarts it even when I do the following as root...

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service



apachectl stop

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service


apachectl -k stop   
httpd (no pid file) not running
```

If I 'killall httpd' it just comes back. If I kill the main root httpd process in Activity Monitor, it comes right back. Restart the computer, it's still running.

I just want to permanently kill httpd so I can do an alternate installation, possibly with brew or on another machine. I don't want it running and I don't understand what keeps relaunching httpd on me.

Answer (score 1):

The command you mentioned first works for me. I just added 'sudo'

local:~ mac$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

Answer (score 1):

The solution explained in Answer 1 did not work for me when Mojave server.app was installed.

I had to use this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serviceproxy.plist
```